# Is $W(T)$ always non-empty?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

For $T\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, the numerical range of $T$ is defined as
$$W(T)=\{\langle T x\; |\;x\rangle:\;x \in \mathcal{H}\;\;\hbox{and}\;\|x\|=1\},$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$.

Is $W(T)$ always non-empty?

And thank you

Comment: What is ${\cal H}$?

Comment: Does ${\cal H}$ contain an element of unit norm?

Comment: If $x\neq 0$ then $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is an element of unit norm and it belongs to $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: So, if ${\cal H}$ is non empty, how could $W(T)$ possibly be empty?

Comment: Rather, if $\mathcal{H}$ has a nonzero element, then $W(T)$ will be nonempty.

Comment: @MichaelLee: Thanks for catching my error.

Comment: I think Michael should since he hit the correct point :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{H}$ contains a nonzero element $x$, then $\mathcal{H}$ necessarily contains an element $e = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ such that $\|e\| = 1$. Therefore, for $\mathcal{H}\neq \{0\}$, we let $e\in \mathcal{H}$ such that $\|e\| = 1$, and then we will have $\langle Te, e\rangle\in W(T)$, so $W(T)\neq \emptyset$.